# Is there any balance condition for the rope?

Tags: data-structures

I just read the [Rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29) article, and didn't find any balance condition for the rope. Does it means, that any binary tree with short strings in leaves, is a rope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does it means, that any binary tree with short strings in leaves, is a rope?

Yes. Depending on the implementation there *can* be balancing strategies but this is by no means necessary.

Often, applications which use ropes stil expect relatively few nodes so the overhead of having a balance strategy isn’t worth it, both in terms of effort to implement, and in the (small) runtime overhead which it entails.

Answer (score 0):

The original rope paper does mention a rebalancing strategy which is based on Fibonacci numbers.
"Ropes: an Alternative to Strings", by Boehm, Atkinson, and Plass, in SOFTWARE--PRACTICE AND EXPERIENCE, VOL. 25(12), 1315–1330 (DECEMBER 1995)

I agree that many applications only use a few nodes which means they get the benefit of using rope without having to worry about rebalancing. But, if Rope is offered in a library it would definitely need to keep the tree balanced as it is not aware of application requirements. See the BigList implementation in the PowerCollection library from Wintellect for reference:

https://github.com/timdetering/Wintellect.PowerCollections/blob/master/Source/PowerCollections/BigList.cs